# Flink-SQL Windowed-Table join?

Tags: java, sql, apache-flink, flink-streaming

Due to restrictions, I am only able to use `Flink v 1.4.2`. I am looking into Windowed Joins.

**CustomObj.java (POJO)**

```
class CustomObj{
   public long timestampVal; 
   public int value;
}
```

I have 2 datastreams like:

```
StreamExecutionEnvironment currentEnv = getEnv();
currentEnv.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime);
StreamTableEnvironment tableEnv = TableEnvironment.getTableEnvironment(currentEnv); TableEnvironment.getTableEnvironment(currentEnv);
DataStream<CustomObj> s1 = ...assignTimeStampsAndWatermarks(...)...
DataStream<CustomObj> s2 = ...assignTimeStampsAndWatermarks(...)...

tableEnv.registerDataStream("s1", s1);
tableEnv.registerDataStream("s2", s2);
```

I want to do:

```
SELECT * FROM s1 INNER JOIN s2 ON s1.timestampVal = s2.timestampVal
```

However, `INNER JOIN` for streaming is not supported in `Flink V 1.4.2` so I'm wondering if I can do some sort of TimeWindow join? How does it work exactly?